# Magento 1 datepicker issue selecting date for current month

Tags: magento-1, datepicker

This is my js code for my datepicker:

```
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField : 'scheduled_ajax_update',
        ifFormat : '%d-%m-%Y',
        button : 'scheduled_ajax_update_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
        disableFunc: function(date)  {
            var now = new Date();

            if(date.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) { return true; }
            if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) { return true; }
            if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() < now.getDate()) { return true; }
        }
    });
```

It disables of the past days. My weird issue is that I cannot select any values from the current month, **if my selected day is in the past**. See img:

[image]

In this case I cannot select `27` or `28` .

If I click on the next month and then I go back to my current month I can choose `27` or `28`.

No error messages in the console. Do you know why is this happening :) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093552/magento-date-picker-is-not-working-when-current-date-is-disable) the `currentDateEl` is set null , so I adapted my `disableFunc` script, like:

```
    disableFunc: function(date)  {
        var now = new Date();
        this.currentDateEl = now.getDate();
        if(date.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) { return true; }
        if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) { return true; }
        if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() < now.getDate()) { return true; }
    }
```

Now I am able to select the days from my current month if my current day is in the past.